# Strange extra space in lstlisting when breakindent has been set to 0pt

Tags: listings

In the following example of `lstlisting`, there is a strange extra space in the beginning of the third line. As you can see, it has already been set as `breaklines=true` and `breakindent=0pt`. The issue seems to due to the fact that the code has been indented (which is on purpose). Is there thus some way to fix this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    breaklines   = true,
    breakindent  = 0pt,
    basicstyle   = \small\normalfont\ttfamily,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
A:
  When there is only one natural transformation between two functors, it implies that there is only one consistent way to map objects from the source category to objects in the target category while preserving the relationships between those objects. This uniqueness can have important implications in various mathematical contexts, providing insight into the properties and structure of the categories and functors involved.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The main question is: why using `lstlisting` for this job?

Comment: @egreg This is for writing a demo document. In the end I would like to show the complete code of the current document.

Answer (score 0):

With your example, I don't get the result you've shown but:

[image: with original example]

Here the line breaks can happen *before* a whitespace.

I think, what you want is:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  breaklines   = true,
  breakatwhitespace = true,
  breakindent  = 0pt,
  basicstyle   = \small\normalfont\ttfamily,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
A:
  When there is only one natural transformation between two functors, it implies that there is only one consistent way to map objects from the source category to objects in the target category while preserving the relationships between those objects. This uniqueness can have important implications in various mathematical contexts, providing insight into the properties and structure of the categories and functors involved.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: breakatwhitespace]

or:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    breaklines   = true,
    breakautoindent = false,
    breakindent  = 0pt,
    basicstyle   = \small\normalfont\ttfamily,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
A:
When there is only one natural transformation between two functors, it implies that there is only one consistent way to map objects from the source category to objects in the target category while preserving the relationships between those objects. This uniqueness can have important implications in various mathematical contexts, providing insight into the properties and structure of the categories and functors involved.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: breakautoindent=false]

Or maybe with additional `breakindent=1em`.